# What could cause triggers to be hit for one user in DB, but not for another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a large web application that relies on database (MSSSQL 2008) triggers to perform some of its functions. It offers a web-interface which allows the end user to make form-based changes to the database.

The issue is - when the web application is run with one userid in the apppool, the database triggers don't get triggered (they have logging functionality which enables me to see that); but if I change the userid in the AppPool to another username/password, these triggers are executed. Note that the table updates *are* performed in both scenarios. This is the only difference I can spot between the system behavior under the two different circumstances. Both users have dbo privileges, and are able to read/write into the database.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Thanks.

****UPDATE: 
Neither user is sysadmin; this happens for ALL of my database triggers. ****

****UPDATE #2:
After digging more into the problem, I found out that the logging function was relying on a queue (yes, I know) that has inconsistent behavior for the two user accounts. To me this means that the permissions for both accounts are somehow mismatched and that is most likely the root of the problem. ****

Comment: Could you give some more details about these triggers? It's hard to say without knowing what's supposed to trigger them. Is it possible that the user that fails to trigger them is rolling back their transactions, and the other is committing?

Comment: Don't rely on the triggers own logging to detect this condition. If you haven't already then use SQL Profiler to see exactly what is happening. Maybe the trigger throws an error and gets rolled back. Or maybe the trigger is in a nested transaction that gets rolled back. SQL Profiler is the first thing to check.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner

These are UPDATE After triggers, and the update statement is not encapsulated in a transaction. So it could be that the trigger is fired and immediately fails, but since the two users have the same permissions (and the queries are not user-specific), I have no idea what would could cause this.

Comment: You say they both have dbo - is one of them in fact the actual owner of the database, or sa? (No idea why that would cause a problem yet, just trying to find differences between them). I also suspect we're going to have to see the trigger code (hopefully you can anonymize it sufficiently, if necessary, without taking away the gist of how it works)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, neither is owner of the database, and neither is sa.

Comment: If you can't post the whole trigger code yet, could you at least post the logging portion - I just have a gut feeling that the triggers are firing, but something's stopping them achieving the effects you're expecting.

Comment: Do you use SET CONTEXT_INFO anywhere?

Comment: ..and do users connect under their own credentials? Or the IIS AppPool account? And please post some trigger code

Comment: A constraint violation could be another reason why the trigger fails in some cases and not others. Again, SQL Profiler should answer your question for sure.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help; the SQL Profiler helped narrow it down to the particular stored procedure that was failing and preventing the trigger from being executed correctly. Which allowed me to drill down the problem without making any code changes (simply executing the function for the different user accounts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a nondescript permissions error for that particular user account. When the account was removed from the database and added back in - the triggers, logging, and all related events started working appropriately.

Comment: This is why it's a bad idea to assign permissions directly to users. Always assign permissions to roles then make a user member of the required roles. That way it's much easier to ensure each user gets the right permission set.